# Download processor implementation

Tags: php, redirect, download

I will try to explain on example.
There're files on the web I publish (let's say, something.pdf or thefile.zip). I want, before actual download when user follows the link to file, some php script to be invoked which then will return the requested file. How to do it? Please advise. Thank you!

Edit 1: thanks amadeus. In my case PHP script is located on the other server than web site and files to download = PHP script will need to read file from remote web server and send to client, which is extra traffic... I actually does not need PHP to control file download. It is ok to have it downloaded from the web server, but I want PHP script to be invoked when download is requested (to gather info on who is downloading and how many times).

Edit 2: thank you Pekka. I just realized that it is even more complex. Imagine server1 is webserver with downloadable files on it (no php), and server2 is php server. If I just give "server1/thefile.zip" I will be unable to invoke script from php server. Then it seems I should use "server2/script.php?thefile.zip" which will then just redirect client to the file on server1. Is it the best implementation in given conditions?

Comment: Google _php serve file for download_

Answer (score 0):

> It is ok to have it downloaded from the web server, but I want PHP script to be invoked when download is requested (to gather info on who is downloading and how many times).

That's easy to do by calling

```
header("location: http://externaldomain.com/externalresource.zip
```

from your PHP script when you are done counting.

This will redirect the browser to the external resource.

Comment: Thank you Pekka. It is client-side redirect - will it affect search engine processing negatively?

Comment: @Eugeny what do you mean exactly? Search engine processing of what, the site or the download?

Comment: I mean worsening the search result quality. I just added Edit2 to the original post - please have a look. I know tat search engines do not like redirects... and may not be able to process them properly, so real file contents may disappear from search, or even worse google (for ex) will keep direct link to the file instead of to php script. I hope I am more or less clear on it

Comment: @Eugeny I'm not really sure how search engines handle downloads in general (I think Google just indexes HTML, PDF, SWF, DOCX...). If it's a ZIP download, it wouldn't be indexed anyway. Re your implementation, question yes, that's the usual way to go about it